Angular change detection issues. Why does this hack work?
I am using Angular 17 and have quite a complicated app set up with multiple components, some 3rd party services and a Google Maps instance.
I have a lot of bound properties in my html, some bound to variable using @for(), some simply bound to the value of a let and others to observables using the AsyncPipe.
I apologise for not including any example code. One of the main issues is that whenever I try to set up a simple example it all seems to work fine. I have at least a basic understanding of how data binding is set up so I can only assume that something I have done in my actual build has screwed the process up.
From early on I was finding that, in some instances - usually buttons with their label or disabled values bound, the view was not updating in line with that bound data and I was having to use a lot of detectChanges() to keep everything sweet.
Today even this stopped working and my view would only update if I triggered something that has a listener attached.
This led me to a hack which seems to have cleared all my issues. I simply attached a click listener to the outermost container of my entire app. It doesn't do anything, just an empty function, but now the majority of my problems have gone away.
So whats happening here?
Why does triggering an empty listener at the highest level force change detection more successfully than calling detectChanges()?
Bonus points if you can advise on why change detection is not acting as I would expect it to. What might I be doing in a complex situation that could be breaking it?

The first thing I would check is imperative assignment of async operation results.
For example a subscribe in ngOnInit where the rxjs pipe has async operation inside - the subscribe block would then assign the result correctly to a local variable (which is bound in a template) but you wouldn't see it because the change detection has no idea that something happened. Then you move a mouse or click somewhere or similar and change detection would kickstart and among other things update the template with the result value. A bad solution here would be using signals in the subscribe. A good solution would be to use the rxjs result in the template directly with async pipe instead of the subscribe block.
The same logic applies to e.g. setTimeout and all other async handlers/promises where you do assign the results to local variables and wonder why nothing is visible until something else is happening.
In our clients every component is OnPush and rxjs is used extensively and there is not a single ChangeDetectorRef being used so it can work. Without a code example it's hard to give exact advice though.

That sounds like something I need to look into. I am subscribing to a few BehaviourSubjects in my ngOnInit methods. I never figured that would be an issue but I see what you are saying. If that's the issue then I'm due a bit of a refactoring session :|

I've been banging my head against this all day. I have an array held in a service, that array gets populated with items from localStorage. I bind a view to that array (have tried both *ngFor and @for) but as items are added to the array, the view does not update?? I've tried directly binding to the array variable and to an observable using the async pipe. In all attempts the view only updates when roll over my map or click a button?? Am I missing something obvious here?
